# Can i use "one day" for the past?

Tags: grammar

Can i use "one day" to talk about something happen in the past? 
For example, can i say "I went to Paris one day"? 
If this is grammatically correct, does it mean that i spent exact 1 day in Paris?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We use "one day" to talk about things we have a fairly vague desire or ambition to do in the future. For example  "I want to go to Paris one day". However it does not mean that you only want to go for a single day, indeed you could say "I want to live in Paris one day" which would suggest that you would really like to move there permanently.

If you want to talk about something you did once but don't want to include any details you would use "once", for example "I went to Paris once". This would suggest that you have only been there once but does not say how long you stayed. However if you went there many times but did something specific on one occasion ypu might say something like "I went to Paris once and saw Paris St Germain play Man United".

If you lived there permanently for a while you could say "I lived in Paris once".

The only way in which you can use "one day" to refer to the past is to invert the word order. You can say "One day I went to Paris" but not "I went to Paris one day".

In summary, no, "I went to Paris one day" is not used to speak about the past. No native speaker would do that.

Comment: You would only use 'one day' with reference to the past when telling a story - "One day Goldilocks went for a walk in the woods." In speaking of your own experiences you would use 'once'.

Comment: Thanks @BoldBen for your clear explanation. Actually i just want to name my photo album in Facebook so i guess i want it sounds like a story about the past ^^

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is perfectly correct and the meaning of one day is that it happened upon some day in the past. It doesn't specify anything about the duration though, it just states that it has already happened.

Answer (score 0):

> "I went to Paris **one day**"?

If this is grammatically correct [ it is], does it mean that i spent exact 1 day in Paris? [No - length of stay is not defined and signifies an event in the past].

**one day**. [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/131358?rskey=XOnZoZ&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid33542081) This sense of the phrase is from Oxford English Dictionary:

> on a particular day in the past; on some unspecified day in the
>   future. Cf. day n. Phrases

"I’d like to go to Mexico again one day. This signifies an event in the future.

Comment: It is gramatically correct but it is not colloquial, it sounds strange to me.